# help problem to synchronize bitcoin wallet core

Tags: bitcoin-core

I have about 20 usd trapped in an old version, it is version 0.9.3 of the bitcoin kernel.
I urgently need them to pay a significant debt.
Every time I want to pass them to a stock exchange, the wallet freezes my PC and an error appears to synchronize first someone knows or someone who keeps his wallet synchronized. please, help or any other user that exists in this version, where I can get the bootstrap of utorrent
I try to synchronize it normally it stays stuck a week probe adding nodes and it does not work anymore I do not know what to do
Please help. Bitcoin is all I have left to pay my debts. I lost all my assets.
help I believe in the future with bitcoin I believe in satoshi nakamoto help please

Comment: Export your private key for that addresses using `dumpprivkey`, and import it into a light wallet such as Electrum

Answer (score 1):

Install the latest version of Bitcoin Core, [Bitcoin Core 0.17.0](https://bitcoincore.org/en/releases/0.17.0/). The wallet format has not changed significantly and the software always maintains compatibility with older wallets, so your wallet should work in 0.17.0. You will still need to wait as there will be a database upgrade that takes place and it will need to finish syncing the blockchain.

0.17.0 can be installed on top of your existing installation. It will not delete any of your data. Your wallet does not need to be moved. However, as always, you should always have a backup of your wallet on hand.

If you cannot wait for that, then you can export the private keys for your addresses and import them into another wallet such as Electrum. You can do this by using the `dumpprivkey <address>` command in the Debug Console. `<address>` is the address that you want the private key for.